# Karate - How to deal with unicode characters?

Tags: unicode, karate

I want to send a Unicode string as a request parameter like this:

```
{"mobile": "۹۸.۹۱۲۳۴۳۰۴۱۲"}
```

but Karate send it like this instead:
    {"mobile": "??.??????????"}
I've tried to read Unicode text from a file contains my text:

```
۹۸.۹۱۲۳۴۳۰۴۱۲
```

then read and send it this way:

```
* def persianMobile1 = read('classpath:account/unicode/persian.mobile.txt')

        Given url karate.get('urlBase') +  "account/activateMobileByVerificationCode"
        And request
      """
      {
       "mobile":#(persianMobile1),
       "code":#(defaultVerificationCode)
      }
      """
```

Same problem occurred. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks peter for your answer, I couldn't test that code because I'm not a java developr, I'm just a tester :D, I don't know how to deal with your answer, Out project is using Gradle.

Comment: ok. I'm not that familiar with Gradle, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `maven-surefire-plugin` in your `pom.xml` to use the `UTF-8` file encoding. Add this `<plugin>` if it is not there already.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

EDIT: looks like OP is using Gradle. You need to get Karate (which I assume is run via JUnit) to have the JVM file.encoding set to UTF-8 - to fix this.

Here is a link that should help you do this in Gradle: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/no-possibility-to-set-file-encoding-for-junit-tests-in-gradle-2-13-and-odler/17223

I suggest you work with a Java dev if you need to.