# Karate - How to import a json file like karate-config.js

Tags: json, unit-testing, karate

I have unicode data in my karate-config.js like this:

```
function f() {
    return {
        status0persianMessage: "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد",
   };
}
```

when I try to use #(status0persianMessage) it's ok.
I have another file names data.json like this:

```
    {
  "first_name": {
    "first": "احسان"
  }

    }
```

I import this file like this:

- def data = read('classpath:data.json')

But when I try to use #(data.first_name.first), my data is: ?????.
How to import my data.json like karate-config.js?

Comment: Please accept Peter's response as answer if his suggestion fixed the issue you faced, this will help the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get Karate (which I assume is run via JUnit) to have the JVM file.encoding set to UTF-8 - to fix this. To do this in Maven, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988963/143475

Here is a link that should help you do this in Gradle: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/no-possibility-to-set-file-encoding-for-junit-tests-in-gradle-2-13-and-odler/17223

I suggest you work with a Java dev if you need to. I have no idea if the below works, but based on the above link:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
   systemProperty "file.encoding", "UTF-8"
}
```